# Is MS Azure Active Directory account mandatory to implement oauth for office 365?

Tags: oauth, office365, msdn

To access office 365 mails using Oauth, do I need Azure account?

Can't I use normal office 365 or exchange server account to create the application?

Answer (score 0):

With Office 365, an instance of Azure active Directory is automatically provisioned for your O365 tenant. You need to setup an Azure account/subscription to access the AAD configuration via the Azure portal but you do not need to pay anything additional. Your O365 tenant admin will have access to the Azure portal.

To create an application that leverages O365 credentials for authentication, you must register your application with your AAD instance. There's lots of documentation on the Azure docs site, with samples and more detailed guidance.